# Assign Enum to Variable in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums, runtime-error

How can I assign an [enum](/questions/tagged/enum) to a variable and access its value later? I thought this would be pretty simple, but every time I try to assign the `enum` value to a variable (no type mismatches or warnings in Xcode appear) my app crashes with an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** error.

Here's how I setup my `enum` in my header file (`BarTypes.h`):

```
typedef enum {
    BarStyleGlossy,
    BarStyleMatte,
    BarStyleFlat
} BarDisplayStyle;
```

No issues there (reading and using the values at least). However, when I create a variable that can store one of the `enum` values (*BarStyleGlossy*, *BarStyleMatte*, or *BarStyleFlat*) then try to set that variable, the app crashes. Here's how I setup and use the variable:

```
//Header
@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) BarDisplayStyle barViewDisplayStyle; //I've also tried just using (nonatomic) and I've also tried (nonatomic, assign)

//Implementation
@synthesize barViewDisplayStyle;

- (void)setupBarStyle:(BarDisplayStyle)displayStyle {
    //This is where it crashes:
    self.barViewDisplayStyle = displayStyle;
}
```

Why is it crashing here? **How do I store the value of an enum in a variable?** I think the issue has to do with a lack of understanding about `enums` on my end, however if I follow conventional variable setup and allocation, etc. this should work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Please note that I'm new to `enum`s, so my vocabulary here may be a bit mixed up (forgive me - and feel free to make an edit if you know what I'm trying to say).

I found a few references about `enums` across the web:

- [What is a typedef enum in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707512/what-is-a-typedef-enum-in-objective-c)
- [Using enum types as properties in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627501/using-enum-types-as-properties-in-objective-c)
- [How to create global enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606814/how-to-create-global-enum)
- [How do I define and use an ENUM in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212080/how-do-i-define-and-use-an-enum-in-objective-c)
- I also tried searching [Apple's Developer site](https://developer.apple.com) but only came up with results about types for Apple APIs (ex. Foundation, UIKit, etc.)

EDIT: Here's how I call the `setupBarStyle` method:

```
BarView *bar = [[BarView alloc] init];
[bar setupBarStyle:displayStyle];
```

Comment: show the call to the setupBarStyle method

Comment: @Wain Sure will! I made an edit to my question (edit #1)

Comment: Compiled and ran your code without any crash. Please add a crash log.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just in case anyone out there is still trying to figure out how to assign an enum value to an enum typed variable or property...
Here is an example using a property.

In the header file...

```
@interface elmTaskMeasurement : NSObject

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MeasurementType) {
    D,
    N,
    T,
    Y,
    M
};

@property(nonatomic) MeasurementType MeasureType;

@end
```

In the file where the object is created...

```
elmTaskMeasurement *taskMeasurement = [[elmTaskMeasurement alloc] init];

taskMeasurement.MeasureType = (MeasurementType)N;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you implement is called `setupBarStyle:`, but you call `setupBarShape:` on the object.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo transferring the method call to my question. I've fixed it now

Comment: @RazorSharp (I always wonder how possibly copy-paste can cause such typos...)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error myself but the error was caused by a different bug I off course create myself.

The setter of my property "myApplicationState" was as follows:

```
-(void)setApplicationStyle:(myApplicationStyle)applicationStyle{
    self.applicationStyle = applicationStyle;
    //some more code
}
```

Off course this would result in an endless loop because in the setter, the setting is called again, and again, and again.

It had to be:

```
-(void)setApplicationStyle:(myApplicationStyle)applicationStyle{
    _applicationStyle = applicationStyle;
    //some more code
}
```